# Average of 3 years of sales

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm still quite new at Power BI but i have a table that is similar to this:

| Year | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 335 |
| 2019 | 730 |
| 2020 | 430 |
| 2020 | 358 |

There is more information in the table but as you can see i have multiple different sales entries for each year and the data dates from 2018-2023. I would like to find the average of all the sales from 2020-2022. I am expecting 1 figure (adding all the sales from 2020-2022 then diving it by 3) to use in the line y axis.

I started writing a new measure but i got stuck after this. I am hoping to get some help updating this to give me the correct figure.

```
3_year_avg = SUMX(FILTER(
 'table',
'table'[year] > "2019"); 'table'[sales])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this below-

```
3_year_avg = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
         all('table'),
         'table'[year] > "2019"
    ),
    'table'[sales]
)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for the help but i get an error saying the syntax for  ';'  is incorrect. Do you know what the issue could be?